# How to set minimum key interval to x264enc element of gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer

I'm working on a *gstreamer* application that uses **`x264enc`** element. According to the document below, **there is no property to specify minimum key interval** while there's `key-int-max`.
https://thiblahute.github.io/GStreamer-doc/x264-1.0/index.html?gi-language=c

On the other hand, there's `--min-keyint` property in FFmpeg option.
https://sites.google.com/site/linuxencoding/x264-ffmpeg-mapping

How to set minimum key interval to x264enc element of gstreamer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the `option-string` property in `x264enc`:

```
option-string       : String of x264 options (overridden by element properties)
                        flags: readable, writable
                        String. Default: ""
```

This basically hands of options to `libx264`. Unfortunately I forgot the syntax that you need to use here.. Could have been `option-string=min-keyint=x` but perhaps double checking the `x264enc` element's code should give some more hints here.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!